# integral over Green's function of a $d$-Ball

Tags: integration, harmonic-functions, boundary-value-problem, greens-function, poissons-equation

I'm studying for an exam on PDE's and I'm stuck trying to solve the following problem.
This is in context of the following boundary value problem:
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
-\Delta u \equiv 0,&\text{in } B(0,r)\\
u \equiv g,&\text{on } \partial B(0,r)
\end{cases}
\end{align}
where $r>0$, $B(0,r)\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is the ball of radius $r$ and $g\in C(\partial B(0,r))$.
The problem then asks to show, that the Green's function $G$ of the above BVP satisfies
$$\int_{B(0,r)}G(x,y)dy = \frac{1}{2d}(r^2-|x|^2)$$
My approach was the following:
I want to use the property of the greens function, namely
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
-\Delta G(x,y) = \delta(x-y),&\text{in } B(0,r)\\
G(x,y) = 0,&\text{on } \partial B(0,r)
\end{cases}
\end{align}
where $\delta$ is the Dirac Delta. I also know, that the following identity holds for general functions $f$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\left(\frac{1}{|\partial B(0,s)|}\int_{\partial B(0,s)}f(y)dS(y)\right) = \frac{s}{d}\frac{1}{| B(0,s)|}\int_{ B(0,s)}\Delta f(y)dy.$$
that means we can compute
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\left(\frac{1}{|\partial B(0,s)|}\int_{\partial B(0,s)}G(x,y)dy\right) &= \frac{s}{d}\frac{1}{| B(0,s)|}\int_{ B(0,s)}\Delta_y G(x,y)dy\\
&=-\frac{s}{d}\frac{1}{| B(0,s)|}\int_{ B(0,s)}\delta(x-y)dy = -\frac{s}{d}\frac{1}{| B(0,s)|}\\
&=-\frac{s}{d}\frac{1}{s^{d}| B(0,1)|} =  -\frac{1}{ds^{d-1}}\frac{1}{| B(0,1)|}
\end{align}
and thus
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{|\partial B(0,s)|}\int_{\partial B(0,s)}G(x,y)dy  = -\frac{1}{d(d-2)s^{d-2}}\frac{1}{| B(0,1)|}+c
\end{align}
for some constant $c$.
Now using that $|\partial B(0,s)| = ds^{d-1}|B(0,1)|$, we get
\begin{align}
\int_{\partial B(0,s)}G(x,y)dy  = -\frac{s}{(d-2)}+cds^{d-1}|B(0,1)|
\end{align}
The constant can be found through the boundary condition on $G$:
\begin{align}
0 = \int_{\partial B(0,r)}G(x,y)dy &= \lim_{s\to r}\int_{\partial B(0,s)}G(x,y)dy  = \lim_{s\to r}\left(-\frac{s}{(d-2)}+cds^{d-1}|B(0,1)|\right)\\
&= -\frac{r}{(d-2)}+cdr^{d-1}|B(0,1)|
\end{align}
thus $c = \frac{1}{d(d-2)r^{d-2}|B(0,1)|}$ and so
\begin{align}
\int_{\partial B(0,s)}G(x,y)dy  = -\frac{s}{(d-2)}+\frac{1}{(d-2)r^{d-2}}s^{d-1}
\end{align}
We can then compute
\begin{align}
\int_{B(0,r)}G(x,y)dy &= \int_0^r\int_{\partial B(0,s)}G(x,y)dy ds = \int_0^r\left(-\frac{s}{(d-2)}+\frac{1}{(d-2)r^{d-2}}s^{d-1}\right)ds\\
&= -\frac{r^2}{2(d-2)}+\frac{1}{d(d-2)r^{d-2}}r^{d} = \frac{r^2}{d-2}\left(\frac{1}{d}-\frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{r^2}{2d} .
\end{align}
That is close to the answer it is supposed to be but not quite it. Can someone give me a hint on how to correct my approach and how the dependency on $x$ comes in?